# Is saying "LMAO" haram?

Tags: halal-haram, reference-request

Is saying "[LMAO](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lmao)" haram?

Mention hadiths or verses of the Quran in favour of your answer.
I searched them up on google, but didn't find any satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. In my opinion since ass is still considered a vulgar word that it should not be used. Instead you can say laugh my head off,  lol (laugh out loud) or rofl (rolling on floor laughing).

Muslims should try to refrain from using vulgar, obscene, curse words.

Before going to the ahadith we need to understand what vulgar and obscenity means.

**Vulgar**
(adjective)
lacking sophistication or good taste; unrefined.

**Obscene**
(adjective)
offensive to morality or decency; indecent; depraved:

**Hadith #1**
'Abdullah reported ALLAH Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:

Truth leads one to Paradise and virtue leads one to Paradise and the person tells the truth until he is recorded as truthful, and lie leads to obscenity and obscenity leads to Hell, and the person tells a lie until he is recorded as a liar.
Prophet (peace and blessings of ALLAH be upon him): “Whoever hears the call to prayer and does not respond, his prayer is not valid, except the one who has an excuse.” (Sahih Muslim)

**Hadith #2**
"I asked 'Aishah about the character of the Messenger of ALLAH. She said: 'He was not obscene, nor uttering obscenities, nor screaming in the markets, he would not return an evil with an evil, but rather he was pardoning and forgiving." (Tirmidhi)

**Hadith #3**
Abu Hurairah narrated that the Messenger of ALLAH said:
"Al-Haya is from faith, and faith is in Paradise. Obscenity is from rudeness, and rudeness is in the Fire." (Tirmidhi)

**Hadith #4**
It was narrated from Abu Bakrah that the Messenger of ALLAH (ﷺ) said:
“Modesty is part of faith, and faith will be in Paradise. Obscenity in speech is part of harshness and harshness will be in Hell.’” (Ibn Majah)

**Hadith #5**
The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Whoever does not give up false statements (i.e. telling lies), and evil deeds, and speaking bad words to others, ALLAH is not in need of his (fasting) leaving his food and drink." (Bukhari)

**Have a nice day!**